# ipconfig /all does not list correct dns server

Tags: cmd, dns

I am trying to find the DNS server used by my PC, but everywhere says to run the command ipconfig /all

The problem with that is when running that command, my DNS server and the default gateway are the same

My router homepage also does not list it in the status page.

Can someone tell me a quick and easy way to find my DNS server?

Answer (score 0):

Your router's homepage is probably at the gateway address. Setting the router as the DNS (as happens with DHCP sometimes) simply means that your router is probably going to be relaying all the DNS requests to its next higher source of authority. There are advantages to doing this, as rather than simply passing on the DNS address to the clients, the ROUTER (which is hopefully trusted) can relay the request up the chain using a variety of techniques which may be more secure than allowing devices on your inside network to just go and look it up themselves.

You would have to look at the admin page of your router to find that DNS information.

Note that some browsers now bypass this "classic" form of DNS altogether.

Comment: my dog guards the internet router so i cant see the admin password

Comment: Well the short answer is that your DNS server IS the process running on the Gateway router. Like any other DNS, depending on which name you are looking up, if it doesn't know the answer it's going to play pass the parcel until someone on the chain knows the address. So even if you had the IP address of the next DNS on the line, that may well just be asking someone else. You can probably use any DNS you want to, if your ISP allows the requests to go out of your firewall and the replies to come back (most do, I think).